# Сохранение текста из формы в документ

Tags: php

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на на кнопку данные из формы сохранялись в документ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого надо вытащить данные из формы средствами PHP. Если вы используете метод POST, то так:

```
<form method='post'>   // типа форма с методом POST
<input type='text' name='info'>  // текстовое поле
<input type='submit' name='submiter'> // кнопка отправки на сервер
</form>
```

-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submiter']))  // если отправили форму...то
{    
    $info = $_POST['info'];      // получаем значение текстового поля и..
    $f = fopen('file.html','a+');  // открываем файл для записи в конец =)
    fputs($f,$info);        //  записываем текстовое значение поля в файл
    fclose($f);             // закрываем файл.    
}
?>
```

**Хотя для метода GET все будет точно так же, только юзайте массив не `$_POST`, а `$_GET` =)**